# How to stop Socket Server in Windows From C#?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to Stop Server at form close but its not working. It Throws exception at

clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

> Exception : A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

I tried to Stop Server at different places but its not working

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serverSocket = new TcpListener(9361);
        clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        Thread listen = new Thread(listenClients);
        listen.Start();

    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        serverSocket.Stop();
    }

    public void listenClients()
    {

        serverSocket.Start();
        while ((true))
        {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            Thread listen = new Thread(readClient);
            listen.Start();

        }
    }

    public void broadcast(Image img)
    {
        CamView.Image = img; 
    }  //en

    private void readClient()
    {
        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesFrom))
                    {
                        Image mss = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        broadcast(mss);
                    }
            }
            catch 
            {

            }
        } //end while
    } //end readClint
```

Comment: That exception is supposed to happen, what where you expecting `AcceptTcpClient` to return if you stopped the service before a client connected?

Comment: Also your `readClient` is not implmented safely. even though you called `Read` with  `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` as the count the `Read` call may fill anywhere between 1 and `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` bytes, it will return the number of bytes it filled in the `int` that is returned from the function call.

Comment: I just want to stop server on form close whether a client connected or not

Comment: Also you are not guaranteed that your `Image` will be sent in one packet. You need to implement some kind of "[Message Framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)" to make sure your image was received completly before you pass it off to `broadcast`

Comment: But how  i can stop server ?

Comment: `serverSocket.Stop();` and handle the error when it shows up. As I said in my first comment, that error is supposed to happen. Just handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is perfectly valid in your case - `serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking operation that either returns a `TcpClient` instance or throws a `SocketException`.

Here is how you can solve this problem without changing the architecture of the application:

```
try
{
    serverSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
}
catch(SocketException e)
{
    if (e.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.Interrupted)
        throw;
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to put the starting of the thread inside the try block too otherwise it will just start a new thread using the `serverSocket` from the last connected client (or null if no one has connected)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks, you are absolutely correct about the problem, though I will use a slightly different solution - see the corrected version

Answer (score -1):

please keep Try catch block inside following code.

```
serverSocket = new TcpListener(9361);
    clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    Thread listen = new Thread(listenClients);
    listen.Start();
```